# Create List using Builder Pattern in Java

Tags: java, java-8, lombok, builder

I am having a class that takes a string and a List object . I am able to create a List object separately using builder and pass it to another builder to create an object . But it does not looks like a nice way . Is their any way to merge these 2 builders in one builder.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class CustomerRequest{
private String cutspec;
private List<Customer> listOfcustomer;
}
```

Current Implementation

```
Customer customer = Customer.builder().conditionType("valueCondition").key("customerNo")
            .operator("=").value(customerId).build();
    
    List<Customer> listOfcustomer = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfcustomer.add(customer);

    return CustomerRequest.builder().name("John").simplecustomer(listOfcustomer).build();
```

Comment: Can you show what kind usage are you looking for? *How* do you want the "merged" builder to be used?

Comment: How does a Lombok generated builder end up with a method name of `simplecustomer` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Java 9's List.of()-Method you can do:

```
return CustomerRequest.builder()
    .name("John")
    .simplecustomer(List.of(
        Customer.builder().conditionType("valueCondition").key("customerNo")
            .operator("=").value(customerId).build()
    ))
    .build();
```

Just be aware that the resulting List is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom builder for the **CustomerRequest** class. Then you can directly build the **Customer** object inside the **CustomerRequest** builder, and there's no need to create a separate list and then pass it to the **CustomerRequest** builder.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class CustomerRequest {
    private String cutspec;
    private List<Customer> listOfcustomer;

    public static class CustomerRequestBuilder {
        private List<Customer> listOfcustomer = new ArrayList<>();

        public CustomerRequestBuilder customer(Customer customer) {
            this.listOfcustomer.add(customer);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

After that,you can directly create a **CustomerRequest** object with its associated **Customer** objects using the custom builder:

```
Customer customer = Customer.builder()
        .conditionType("valueCondition")
        .key("customerNo")
        .operator("=")
        .value(customerId)
        .build();
return CustomerRequest.builder()
        .cutspec("someCutSpec")
        .customer(customer) 
        .build();
```